# Docusign powerforms integration with SPA to send a link for end user to sign

Tags: content-management-system, docusignapi, powerform

I have the following scenario - An admin goes to our website form and enters the details like name, email, phone and other information and creates a consent form with above details. But instead of going directly to the powerform in docusign we want to send a link to the employee via email. When the employee clicks on the link, at that time the powerform should open with the details that the admin entered merged. The employee can then sign the document.
is there an example of any such implementation? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for could be achieved a lot easier and simpler without using PowerForms.

Let me explain.

Normally in the DocuSign system, in order for someone to sign an envelope, you need to know their name and email address. That enters them as a recipient of the envelope. The recipient can get an email with the link to sign at that time (remote signing).

Now, PowerForms were introduced to solve the following problem: you do not know who may be signing but you still want to give them a link. So using a DocuSign template, you can generate a link that anyone can click and provide their information. Yes, you can add query parameters to the URL with the name and even email of the signers, but the envelope is only generated when the link is clicked.

So, you have two options: the normal/simple way is to use [our code example for remote signing](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/code-example-request-a-signature-via-email) and generate regular envelopes. No PowerForms. Seems like it will do everything in your scneario.

Second, you can use PowerForms and have some code to generate a custom link for that recipient that is then sent to them via email. We don't recommend this option as this link is a security risk and cannot be removed or expired if leaked (until you remove the entire PowerForm).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Inbar for your prompt help on this. a few follow up questions.

From what I understand is that the app that I have (written in React.js) will be used by the admin to enter the details and then invoke the DocuSign API to create an envelope. 
I believe I cannot invoke the API from my react app directly (using api key). I will need an OAUTH token for which I will need to create a node.js app. is that correct?
And when the token expires how will I renew that?
Thanks

Comment: yes, that is correct. You can renew using a refresh token. Or obtain a new token the same way you go the first one. If you use JWT, you only need consent once and then you can get tokens all the time without user interaction

Comment: If I answered your questions - please mark it as answered. thanks!

Comment: Great, thanks much! Would you have code samples of the above?

Comment: refresh token? https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-code-grant has some information. I have posted a link in the answer with code examples